# flush glossaries super style to left

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, alignment

I am using the glossaries-extra package to create a bilingual glossary. I want to use a modified version of the super style. However I can't flush the glossary entry list to the left side. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
automake,
acronym,
nomain,
nopostdot=true,
nonumberlist,
]{glossaries-extra}


\makeglossaries

\newacronym[user1=interaural time difference]{itd}{ITD}{interaurale Zeitdifferenz}
\newacronym{iid}{IID}{interaurale Intensitätsdifferenz}

%% modsuper glossary display style
\newglossarystyle{modsuper}{%
\glossarystyle{super}%
\renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\[2pt]}%
}


\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}
\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{%
\ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
{ (\glscurrentfieldvalue)}%
{}%
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Räumliches Hören}

Die \gls{itd} beschreibt die Zeitdifferenz zwischen den Ankunftszeiten des Schallsignals an den Ohren. Die \gls{iid} ist die Differenz der Schalldruckpegel zwischen beiden Ohren. \gls{itd} und \gls{iid} spielen beim räumlichen Hören eine wesentliche Rolle.

\printglossary[%
type=\acronymtype,
title=Akronyme und Abkürzungen,
toctitle=Akronyme und Abkürzungen,
style=modsuper,
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I would use the altree style as well. But there i didn't find out how to adjust the vertical space between the glossary entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super style uses a (super)tabular with `{lp{\glsdescwidth}}` as tabular preamble. This gives a default margin of a `\tabcolsep`. You can suppress the margin with @{}:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
automake,
acronym,
nomain,
nopostdot=true,
nonumberlist,
]{glossaries-extra}


\makeglossaries

\newacronym[user1=interaural time difference]{itd}{ITD}{interaurale Zeitdifferenz}
\newacronym{iid}{IID}{interaurale Intensitätsdifferenz}

%% modsuper glossary display style
\newglossarystyle{modsuper}{%
\glossarystyle{super}%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{@{}lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%<----no margin
    {\end{supertabular}}%
\renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\[2pt]}%
}


\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}
\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{%
\ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
{ (\glscurrentfieldvalue)}%
{}%
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Räumliches Hören}

Die \gls{itd} beschreibt die Zeitdifferenz zwischen den Ankunftszeiten des Schallsignals an den Ohren. Die \gls{iid} ist die Differenz der Schalldruckpegel zwischen beiden Ohren. \gls{itd} und \gls{iid} spielen beim räumlichen Hören eine wesentliche Rolle.

\printglossary[%
type=\acronymtype,
title=Akronyme und Abkürzungen,
toctitle=Akronyme und Abkürzungen,
style=modsuper,
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to fit the glossary width to the textwidth by using for e.g. something like "X" definition from the tabularx environment?